# Hide shipping rate based on product tag doubling shipping cost

Tags: ruby, shopify, shopifyscripts

Hi, sorry if someone has asked this before. I've searched and haven't been able to find this exact problem. We want to charge a white glove service fee for products with the white-glove tag but keep the option for free shipping. The following script works for a mixed cart (product with and without the white-glove tag), but it doubles the cost? I made this with a script generator so I know it's very bloated, as well.

```
class Campaign
def initialize(condition, *qualifiers)
    @condition = (condition.to_s + '?').to_sym
    @qualifiers = PostCartAmountQualifier ? [] : [] rescue qualifiers.compact
    @line_item_selector = qualifiers.last unless @line_item_selector
    qualifiers.compact.each do |qualifier|
      is_multi_select = qualifier.instance_variable_get(:@conditions).is_a?(Array)
      if is_multi_select
        qualifier.instance_variable_get(:@conditions).each do |nested_q|
          @post_amount_qualifier = nested_q if nested_q.is_a?(PostCartAmountQualifier)
          @qualifiers << qualifier
        end
      else
        @post_amount_qualifier = qualifier if qualifier.is_a?(PostCartAmountQualifier)
        @qualifiers << qualifier
      end
    end if @qualifiers.empty?
  end
def qualifies?(cart)
    return true if @qualifiers.empty?
    @unmodified_line_items = cart.line_items.map do |item|
      new_item = item.dup
      new_item.instance_variables.each do |var|
        val = item.instance_variable_get(var)
        new_item.instance_variable_set(var, val.dup) if val.respond_to?(:dup)
      end
      new_item
    end if @post_amount_qualifier
    @qualifiers.send(@condition) do |qualifier|
      is_selector = false
      if qualifier.is_a?(Selector) || qualifier.instance_variable_get(:@conditions).any? { |q| q.is_a?(Selector) }
        is_selector = true
      end rescue nil
      if is_selector
        raise "Missing line item match type" if @li_match_type.nil?
        cart.line_items.send(@li_match_type) { |item| qualifier.match?(item) }
      else
        qualifier.match?(cart, @line_item_selector)
      end
    end
  end
  def run_with_hooks(cart)
    before_run(cart) if respond_to?(:before_run)
    run(cart)
    after_run(cart)
  end
  def after_run(cart)
    @discount.apply_final_discount if @discount && @discount.respond_to?(:apply_final_discount)
    revert_changes(cart) unless @post_amount_qualifier.nil? || @post_amount_qualifier.match?(cart)
  end
  def revert_changes(cart)
    cart.instance_variable_set(:@line_items, @unmodified_line_items)
  end
end
class ConditionallyHideRates < Campaign
  def initialize(condition, customer_qualifier, cart_qualifier, li_match_type, line_item_qualifier, rate_selector)
    super(condition, customer_qualifier, cart_qualifier, line_item_qualifier)
    @li_match_type = (li_match_type.to_s + '?').to_sym
    @rate_selector = rate_selector
  end
  def run(rates, cart)
    rates.delete_if { |rate| @rate_selector.match?(rate) } if qualifies?(cart)
  end
end
class Selector
  def partial_match(match_type, item_info, possible_matches)
    match_type = (match_type.to_s + '?').to_sym
    if item_info.kind_of?(Array)
      possible_matches.any? do |possibility|
        item_info.any? do |search|
          search.send(match_type, possibility)
        end
      end
    else
      possible_matches.any? do |possibility|
        item_info.send(match_type, possibility)
      end
    end
  end
end
class ProductTagSelector < Selector
  def initialize(match_type, match_condition, tags)
    @match_condition = match_condition
    @invert = match_type == :does_not
    @tags = tags.map(&:downcase)
  end
  def match?(line_item)
    product_tags = line_item.variant.product.tags.to_a.map(&:downcase)
    case @match_condition
      when :match
        return @invert ^ ((@tags & product_tags).length > 0)
      else
        return @invert ^ partial_match(@match_condition, product_tags, @tags)
    end
  end
end
class RateNameSelector < Selector
  def initialize(match_type, match_condition, names)
    @match_condition = match_condition
    @invert = match_type == :does_not
    @names = names.map(&:downcase)
  end
  def match?(shipping_rate)
    name = shipping_rate.name.downcase
    case @match_condition
      when :match
        return @invert ^ @names.include?(name)
      else
        return @invert ^ partial_match(@match_condition, name, @names)
    end
  end
end
CAMPAIGNS = [
  ConditionallyHideRates.new(
    :all,
    nil,
    nil,
    :all,
    ProductTagSelector.new(
      :does_not,
      :match,
      ["white-glove"]
    ),
    RateNameSelector.new(
      :does,
      :match,
      ["White Glove"]
    )
  )
].freeze
CAMPAIGNS.each do |campaign|
  campaign.run(Input.shipping_rates, Input.cart)
end
Output.shipping_rates = Input.shipping_rates
```

Aside from doubling the cost, I'm sure there has to be a cleaner way to do this. I apologize for the formatting. Total newbie.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the double cost-I had the service fee twice in my shipping rates! But I'm sure there's a cleaner way to write this?